# What's the Appropriate Word to Say You're 'Dazzled' by a Nice Smell?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, phrase-requests, sense-verbs

Imagine there's food being cooked on stove and you feel the pleasant smell and it somehow makes you mad! You want to keep smelling or walk to the kitchen and get some of it to eat.

What verb would you use to explain the situation?

The only verb that comes to my mind is *dazzle*, but I check it in the dictionary (LDOCE-subscription only) and the second definition is:

> to impress someone very much by being or doing something very exciting and unusual - used especially in news reports
>
> *The Princess’s off-the-shoulder dress dazzled the waiting crowds.*
>
> *As a speaker he would dazzle listeners with his brilliant wordplay and witty remarks.*

And that doesn't seem to be right for this situation and we also know that the other meaning is when you're *dazzled* by a light of some sort.

Checking the Thesaurus I notice the other verb *to be knocked out*, but again I don't think it's appropriate.

In Persian we have a general word for being *drunk* and we'd use it for pleasant smells as well, so what's the *smell* equivalent of being dazzled or drunk in English?

To explain this a bit more, I'm looking for a word that would describe the images below:

[image]

[image: nice scent]

Comment: These images illustrate the inadequacies of the language.

Comment: I don't think there is a single word, but I would say a phrase would likely contain "aroma" or "bouquet", which both refer to the odors of foods in a positive manner.  Other possible, though perhaps somewhat overly poetic, words might be "perfume" and "fragrance".

Comment: You're going at this the wrong way. Instead of trying to find a verb to use in a passive construction, either try something more active (think: pie as agent of scrumptious aroma) or use a metaphor. Not all writing problems can be solved with a thesaurus.

Comment: What's wrong with *drunk*? -overcome or dominated by a strong feeling or emotion: drunk with power; drunk with joy. -[TFD](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/drunk)
; in this case, hunger or desire.

Comment: how about `snozzled`? okay - might not be a word, but can I coin it?

Answer (score 24):

[Intoxicate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intoxicate): to excite or please (someone) in a way that suggests the effect of alcohol or a drug.

I was **intoxicated** by the intoxicating aroma coming from the kitchen

Comment: If you ask me, *...intoxicated by the intoxicating...* is a little redundantly redundant if you ask me.

Comment: You're absolutely and positively correct! Either parenthesis or brackets around "intoxicating" would have helped to avoid that issue, but "the intoxicating aroma" in its pure and undiluted form smelled so good to me that I just couldn't resist it!

Comment: I hate gluing PVC joints. The smell is intoxicating and if at all possible I head in the other direction for a while.

Comment: “Glue heads” would probably enjoy that “smell,” but yeah, I fudged a bit and used the synonym “aroma,” instead of “smell” with “intoxicating” to try to help to make my case.  You’re right “inTOXICating smells” don’t intoxicate the same way that "intoxicating aromas” do.

Answer (score 11):

[*Bewitched*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bewitched) or any of its many near synonyms seems appropriate:

> To place under one's power by or as if by magic; cast a spell over. - TFD

*captivated*, *entranced*, *enthralled*, *mesmerized*, *transfixed*, etc.

> Rudd brands, arrived at Anchor in 2011 and was immediately *mesmerized* by the aroma of hops permeating the brewery and distillery. - Weekly Pint

Comment: I'm not sure about *bewitched* (it's much stronger than *dazzled* and you're usually bewitched by a person, not a physical phenomenon); however, all the other suggestions work well.

Comment: _Enchanted_ would work as well.

Comment: While technically this definition fits what the OP is looking for, I've personally never heard _bewitched_ used this way, and I'm not sure it applies.

Answer (score 9):

I would use ***drawn*** (*by* or *to*), especially for the aroma of food or drink. It is also a good fit for the pictures that you provided. In the cartoons, the characters are physically drawn to the aroma and it is a depiction of this figurative speech.

> Entering the market you are immediately drawn by the aroma of freshly baked apple cider donuts coming from the ovens. [[Daily Collegian]](http://dailycollegian.com/2012/10/24/top-five-fall-favorites-at-atkins-farms/)
>
> ---
>
> It Makes No Scents Researcher Says Women Drawn By The Aroma Of Male Sweat [[philly.com]](http://articles.philly.com/1996-03-18/news/25638099_1_t-shirts-smell-scientific-speculation)

You can consider ***lured*** or ***allured*** if it is a scent like of a flower or perfume. You can apply to animals too.

> Bees are lured by the scent of flowers.
>
> She was lured by the smell of his aftershave.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I would use ***overpowered***, or ***overcome***.

*I was overcome by the aroma of baking bread, which reminded me that I had not eaten for 24 hours*.

*Dazzling* has to do with light, and the eyes - something altogether different.

Comment: "Overpowered" can easily be (mis-) understood to imply negative impressions, as in "too much smell".

Comment: That's right WS2, as I've already mentioned it in my post, but it also has that second meaning in the dictionary which isn't directly related to lights, but all in all, I know *dazzle* isn't the right word here.

Answer (score 2):

I was **bedazzled** by the aroma of peaches and pineapples coming from the kitchen.

bedazzle -  To dazzle so completely as to make blind, to please irresistibly, enchant [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bedazzled)

Comment: The question is for an **alternative** to *dazzle*, since dazzle specifically refers to the sense of sight.

Comment: dazzle and bedazzle are not synonymous.

Comment: @Centaurus: But doesn't the very definition of "bedazzle" that you quoted *explicitly* refer to "dazzle"?

Answer (score 2):

I like "entranced" or "allured". They have a positive connotation and your pictures both show positive reactions to the scent, while "overpowered" and "overcame" are neutral in tone at best, and easily slip into negative connotation. Inebriated and intoxicated have too many drug connotations. "Bedazzled" seems to visual for me, recalling dazzle camouflage. "Mesmerized" and "transfixed" are typically used to describe the reaction of eyes; although this could be said for entranced as well, scents are often used to get into a trance state.

Answer (score 2):

I think "[entice](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entice)" is a good word in this context.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @somanyJunsus. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Your post would be improved by explaining why you think that, and quoting from your source.

Answer (score 1):

It is not strictly related to the sense of smell, but I would use the word "overwhelmed" in this context.

Comment: The OP is referring to positive smells, such as food. When I think of smells that are "overwhelming", it usually brings to mind *unpleasant* smells, such as sewage, noxious chemical fumes, etc...

Comment: Funny - not me. I can certainly find some nice scents overwhelming as well.

Comment: Interesting. The only times I've heard people use "overwhelming" to refer to a smell is when it's either a very strong and bad smell, or sometimes *too much* (to the point of being unpleasant) of a good smell.

Answer (score 1):

In both those images the character is [carried away](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+carried+away) by the aroma or fragrance. Odors can trigger [olfactory memories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olfactory_memory), perhaps of a delicious slice of home-baked pie, or the pheromones that help bond a baby to a particular pair of maternal breasts.

Comment: You are carried away by emotions; when you get overexcited, over emotional or overworked by something. It can be used either positively or negatively. To be carried away by a smell, is not idiomatic, there may be instances on Google when that combination of words are used but it just sounds odd.

Comment: @Mari-LouA More commonly expressed as "it brings me back" but I can't think of anything closer, and the other answers seem a bit 'off' as well. Maybe there are no good words for swooning to the smell of a warm chocolate croissant.

Answer (score 0):

I think [inebriated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Inebriated)  may convey the idea:

> - exhilarated or stupefied by or as if by alcohol; invigorated.
> - stupefied or excited by a chemical substance.

- the inebriating smell of ripe fruit.
- smelling the inebriating perfumes wafting from vegetable and flower gardens.

(from TFD)

Comment: I would not use *inebriate* for any sense other than actually impaired by chemicals; however, *intoxicate* (suggested by Papa Poule) would work for your example sentences.  Just don't ask me to explain the logic, given that the two words are otherwise synonyms.

Comment: @AmeliaBR - have you ever heard about 'figurative sense'?

Answer (score 0):

Captivated - I was captivated by the rich aroma emanating from the kitchen.

Captivate - to attract and hold the attention or interest of, as by beauty or excellence - in this context - excellence

Comment: perhaps it's escaped your attention but medica's post also suggested *captivated*. I didn't upvote your post for this reason alone.

Answer (score 0):

Seduced. I would have walked past but I was seduced by the scent of baking, of apple pie wafting out her open door.

Answer (score -2):

"Aromatically pleased" or "aromatically delighted."